# How to remove collector in Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I use collector to get information.
I get the information. So i want to deactivate it.
But `delete collector;` is not work.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `Collector#stop()` function:

```js
// `collector` is a Collector instance
collector.on("collect", () => {
  // ...
  if (someCondition) {
    collector.stop(); // This stops the collector from firing events again
  }
});
```

[relevant docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector?scrollTo=stop)

Answer (score 1):

The [`Collector#stop`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector?scrollTo=stop) method would be useful for that, it accepts one parameter that is an array of reasons and further emits the [`Collector#end`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collector?scrollTo=e-end) event.

```js
collector.on("collect", () => {
    collector.stop();
});
```